# How can I move to the next page with Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I need to access only the products on page 2 to 5 of the link below, the variable is at the end of the link where it changes according to the page sequence

[image]

[image]

```
driver.get(url)
classe = driver.find_elements(By. XPATH, "//*[@class='LinksShowcase_UrlContainer__kMj_n']/p")
pages = 1

for x in url:
    driver.get("https://br.ebay.com/b/Portable-Audio/15052/bn_1642614?_pgn="+ str(pages))
    sleep(2)

    for i in classe:
        #pages += 1
        sleep(0.5)
        links.append(i.text)
        print(links)
        sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get pages 2-5, you can iterate using the [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) function:

```py
for page in range(2, 6):
    driver.get("https://br.ebay.com/b/Portable-Audio/15052/bn_1642614?_pgn="+ str(page))
```